# I need to validate a timezone set in Values.yaml

Tags: timezone, kubernetes-helm, react-helmet

I have a Helm template that uses Values.timezone value to set an environment variable, like below:

...
env:
...

- name: "timezone"
  value: {{ Values.timezone | Default "EST" }}

I need to validate the timezone set in Values file following the IANA Timezone Database. If an invalid one is set, I use a default instead so the pod is created with a valid one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

helm includes functions of the [sprig library](https://github.com/Masterminds/sprig) to enhance the [templating functions and pipeline](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/functions_and_pipelines/). you can use those functions in your templates to do stuff, like validating a string or date.

I'd suggest you checkout either the [regex](https://github.com/Masterminds/sprig/blob/master/docs/strings.md#regexmatch-mustregexmatch) or [date](https://github.com/Masterminds/sprig/blob/master/docs/date.md) functions to figure out how to check for the validity of the value.

You could also apply a [json schema file](https://helm.sh/docs/topics/charts/#schema-files) to validate the values of your helm chart. This would be cleaner bcs you wouldn't have to write any templating logic to do so and a schema validation would actually prevent a faulty configured installation.